# How to use SSL in a Java Web project

Tags: java, ssl

i want to use SSL in a Java Web Project, but i do not know anything about this. Is there anyone who could advise me about this? Thanks.

Comment: For what?  Is it just https you want to get running?  Then it should be a matter of setting up the web container according to the documentation and ask in web.xml for the transport to be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the servlet container you are using. I've found [Setting up SSL on Tomcat](http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/) to be a pretty good start for this. For other containers, searching for "ssl container-name" should do the trick.